# how to call google notification in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I need send google notification to every my app user and am able to do it now but question is that I have more than 4000 users and I am sending the notification I am getting some lines in my php page like below

```
sending msg response!
string(38) "id=0:1335083238563622%d38626170036452d"
```

and I am getting this response only 1600(aprox) times, is that means only that no of users are getting notification ? I am worry about this please give me suggestion.

Thanks!